# Need to convert format of Javascript array

Tags: javascript

**home_arr** is a number array, it must be displayed in string format in the expected output

```
var explore_count=[1,1,1,1,1]
var home_arr=[8,9,10,11,12];
var home_count=[1,1,1,1,1];
```

to

```
[['Dates', 'Screen_Home', 'Screen_Explore'],
        ['8', 1, 1],
        ['9', 1, 1],
        ['10', 1, 1],
        ['11', 1, 1],
        ['12', 1, 1],
         ['13', 1, 1],
        ['14', 1, 1]
      ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a `for` loop?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < home_arr.length; i++) { home_arr[i], home_count[i], ... }` – How exactly did that "not work" for you?

Comment: The programming language does _not_ matter at all. This is the same thing everywhere. Please post your code so we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I would be nice to see what you have tried already

Comment: can you add your code in jsbin/plnkr or something?

Comment: @Henry Or, like, *right here* in the question...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/,  https://jsfiddle.net/, http://plnkr.co/ or even here in stackoverflow code

Comment: I am left speechless... Perhaps we should start at the beginning: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that we are not a code writing service. We are here to explain things to you should you not understand them. For this you need to tell us what exactly you don't understand. I have unfortunately made an assumption about what part you don't understand and have given you pointers in the right direction. This was my bad, as apparently there's more to your non-understanding than I thought. Apologies again.

Answer (score 0):

This solution features

- [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

  > The **concat()** method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

  for the header array of your wanted structure and the data, which uses
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

  > The **map()** method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

  The return value is an array with elements from `home_arr` via `a` and from the other arrays `home_count` and `explore_count` via the index `i`.

```js
var explore_count = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    home_arr = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    home_count = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    result = [['Dates', 'Screen_Home', 'Screen_Explore']].concat(
        home_arr.map(function (a, i) {
            return [a.toString(), home_count[i], explore_count[i]];
        })
    );
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```